# iPhone Keynote - present to Apple TV?

Tags: iphone, appletv, keynote

I have an Apple TV and Keynote for the iPhone. Is it possible to display a presentation that I created on the iPhone on Apple TV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately not, certainly not wirelessly.

What you need to do is wait for iOS5 (on the understanding that your phone will support this), for the implementation of the new "screen mirroring over airplay" functionality.